# How to use R script inside H2O Flow?

Tags: r, h2o

I found this information into the H2O Flow documentation :

> H2O Flow supports REST API, R scripts, and CoffeeScript

[H2O Flow Documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html)

Into H2O Flow there are special cells for Scala code, but I didn't found any way to use R code inside the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, R and Python are not supported inside the H2O Flow Web UI.

Try installing RStudio for a nice R IDE.